# How to fix camelcase lint problems in firebase function

Tags: firebase, telegram

I'm currently working on my telegram testing in firebase and I encountered an issue with lint, is there someone that encountered same issue as mine?

ERROR

```
/root/1telegram/functions/src/index.ts
  26:11  error  Identifier 'chat_id' is not in camel case     camelcase
  27:12  error  Identifier 'first_name' is not in camel case  camelcase
  31:7   error  Identifier 'chat_id' is not in camel case     camelcase
  32:22  error  Identifier 'first_name' is not in camel case  camelcase
```

Answer (score 0):

Camel case refers to removing all spaces and underscore, and capitalizing all words but the first one.

E.g. `chat_id` becomes `chatId` and `first_name` becomes `firstName`

If this doesn't work, try to capitalize the first word as well (e.g. `FirstName`); this naming convention (pascal case) is sometimes used interchangeably with camel case.

I hope this helps!